# Sharepoint Client Web web part with google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, dns, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I'm developing SharePoint client web part in SharePoint Add-in(app), client web part create an iframe to open a page in the add-in sub-site, the problem is the browsers see this as different security zone which cause to ask for authentication.

I solved the problem on IE by setting the DNS of the add-in site the same of SharePoint site, SharePoint site: contoso.com, Add-in Site: AddInID.constoso.com, but the problem still exist on google chrome.

Any idea of how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on SharePoint on premise or SPO. If for SPO, since they use claim-base auth, you can let your Chrome to remember your login information and you won't see that popup. 
For on premise, it's a little bit tricky. you have to make sure your host domain and add in domain are in the same internet zone. otherwise, it will popup login information.